# Load SVG files with Xamarin Forms

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms

I am building an app which loads an SVG file (2D Floor plan) and then I need to add click events for each room, table, chair, etc...
I am using normal HTML / Javascript for the website and for the app I am testing the XamSVG component but I am not sure that is the right tool for it.
Any ideas? Can I use WebView? There are other packages available?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @gjfonte, did you sorted it anyway, I am also having the exactly same requirement as you. If you did it can you guide me in adding them.

Comment: Hi @sahithi , yes I managed to get this working using an HybridWebView. You can see the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview