# Plan Interactive SVG with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, svg, interactive

I have a interactive SVG file (Floor plan).I need to add click events for each path (room,floor, etc..)[image]
I am using hybridwebview I am not sure that is the right idea for it. am facing a problem with sending data from class c# ( or from Floor.xaml.cs) to page .html ( i want to attribute id into svg room)
or if there is a simple idea such how to iterate the file .svg ! if i can give the  a x:name a iterate it in Floor.xaml.cs

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ContentPage ..    x:Name="_plan" >

<svg x:Name="buildingPlan" 
                    <clipPath id="001">
                        <path transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,-0,2592,1728)" d="M... Z " />
                    </clipPath>

<g clip-path="url(#001)">
                        <path transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,-0,2592,1728)" d="M 698.8634... Z " fill="#ffffff" />
                        <path transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,-0,2592,1728)" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linejoin="miter" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 6.. Z " />
                   </g>
                    <clipPath id="002">
                        <path transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,-0,2592,1728)" d="M 690.238 1684.95 L 710.438 1684.95 L 710.438 1706.02 L 690.238 1706.02 Z " />
                    </clipPath>
                    <g clip-path="url(#002)">
                        <path transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,-0,2592,1728)" d="M.... Z " fill="#ffffff" />
                        <path transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,-0,2592,1728)" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linejoin="miter" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 700.3378 ... " />
                    </g>
 </svg>
</ContentPage>
```

Floor.xaml.cs :

```
  public partial class Floor: ContentPage{
    
public Floor(){
     InitializeComponent();
//if it is possible to iterate through the svg ?
//buildingPlan.

}
public List<string> GetLocalsId(){
// simple method return list of locals;
}
  }
```

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear.  You mention "sending data from class c# ... to html" but you haven't shown any code where you are attempting to do that.

Comment: thanks for ur answer @Jason , code generic , a method that return a list of locals of building , i was looking here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) and the problem how to fetch the list of locals code into the svg file , the same problem here , (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705580/load-svg-files-with-xamarin-forms)

Comment: SVG is just XML, so you can use standard XML tools to iterate, or there might be other svg packages you can use.

Comment: @Jason , i was able to load svg via (ffimageloading ) but i cant iterate ..

Comment: Will the svg files change or are you always working with the same file?

Comment: it's changeable , but always in same structure

Comment: You will need to modify the xml to add ids before you load it in the viewer

Comment: @Jason , i understand after i modify ids , how can i iterate the svg file and based on id i want to change color , ( if i can do it in xaml.cs ? )

Comment: Read the file into an XDocument. See [`XDocument.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load?view=net-5.0) method. That's an in-memory representation of the XML in your file. It has a `Root` property, which is the top-level [`XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=net-5.0) of the XML. Then either examine `Root` in a debugger, or search for more info about `XElement` class.