# Find circles in image png and trigger a hover event

Tags: xaml, svg, xamarin.forms

I have a plan svg converted into [image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqLJP.png)
i'd like to detect the circles green and trigger a click event and show a tooltip/alert over it .
i posted last time a [Plan Interactive SVG with Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171014/plan-interactive-svg-with-xamarin-forms) but dealing with svg, and i think it is impossible , so i tried to work with png file ,
Plan.xaml

```
<ContentPage..>
    <Image x:Name="_plan" Source="image.png"></Image>
</ContentPage>
else , if there is a simple way with svg.
```

Comment: Off top of my head, Option 1: break the image into small pieces (one for each room) for interaction. Option 2: add a grid layer and set certain positions to be clickable, like define a grid with 10*10, in which (3, 3) and (4, 3) have a green dot and are clickable.

Comment: Just checked the previous thread, how about distributing the paths into different layers: one element with all black lines (svg or paths), each green dot (with number) is another element, and lay them inside a GridView. OR leave the interaction to your page, and use WebView in xamarin.

Comment: Please read about the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion @Shaw  (how about distributing the paths into different layers: one element with all black lines (svg or path) i didnt understand well

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion @enxaneta how the map might solve this problem ! , i have svg file, it is different from this map !

Comment: I've added a comment to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68171014/199364). You're not going to solve this in a png; you need to work with the XML.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its Out Of Scope for StackOverflow. Finding circles in a png would be a research project at best; at worst its impossible due to overlapping elements.